# Php and MySQL searching a string with multiple spaces gives empty array

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm working on an item code search, with strings such as:

- 1231231
- 1231 123
- 123  123

As you can see at the top, the first one has no spaces, second one has, and third one has double spaces in between. That's just a sample of my item codes.

When I try it in localhost, the code works fine with this:

```
$statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM records WHERE record_summary.code = ?");
$statement->execute(array($item_code));
$records = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $response->withStatus(200)->withJson($records);
```

But when I upload it to a hosting already, the 2 samples only work. The code without the space (`1231231`) and the code with a single space (`1231 123`). The code with double spaces (`123  123`) doesn't work. It gives an empty array.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you tried tou use instead of `=` `like '%123 123%'`

Comment: have you checked the value for last sample input. is it contain 2 double space between them as you inserted in to database?

Comment: @G.Mansour can't use that because the format of my codes are different

Comment: try to qute your code by `$this->pdo->quote($item_code);`
Also your can try TRIM Function of mysql [TRIM LINK](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should remove the spaces from the product code and search on that value.

The simplest way to implement this is removing the spaces in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE replace(record_summary.code, ' ', '') = ?
```

However, such a query cannot use indexes, therefore can be slow on a large table. You can add either a generated column or a plain column that is maintained by a trigger, that contain the product code without any spaces. These fields can be indexed and directly searched from the `select` statement.

You can also consider changing the product code field into a numeric field and remove all the spaces from the existing values (or keep it as a text field, but still remove the spaces).

Comment: So I have to remove all the spaces in my item code? or in that query only?

Comment: It's up to you which approach you choose. I do not know if the spaces within the product code have any significance or not. `111 222` and `11 12 22` look the same when you remove the spaces, but may indicate different products in reality.